# Mysql/Php - Current date and time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a query that I want to update a column with the current date time. The column I want to update is of the type datetime.

How can I get it and set it?

```
else{ //If the last update is NULL, It must be players first page load. So set datetime equal to NOW
    $query = "UPDATE `stats` SET `last_ap_update` =    WHERE `member_id` = {$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}"; 
    $queryresult = mysql_query($insertqry);
}
```

Comment: if you use the `timestamp` type for the column it will do this automatically any time the record is updated... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Comment: That won't work for my purposes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `NOW()` in the query would provide this.

```
else{ //If the last update is NULL, It must be players first page load. So set datetime equal to NOW
    $query = "UPDATE `stats` SET `last_ap_update` =  NOW()  WHERE `member_id` = {$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}"; 
    $queryresult = mysql_query($insertqry);
}
```

But if this gets updated anytime the table updates, I would suggest changing the column to `TIMESTAMP` and this will automatically update to the current time for you anytime that record changes.

Comment: Just keep in mind that mySql has issues with time units smaller than seconds. There are a few unsupported patches if you need this feature. You might want to just feed system time while building your request string and work everything around an epoch + macroseconds format (as many MySQL people with auditing needs are doing)

Answer (score 8):

```
else{ //If the last update is NULL, It must be players first page load. So set datetime equal to NOW
    $query = "UPDATE `stats` SET `last_ap_update` =  '".gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'  WHERE `member_id` = {$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}"; 
    $queryresult = mysql_query($insertqry);
}
```

You can use any format you want instead of `gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql function NOW() for this, or you can pase the $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] in there so the query gets cached by mysql.