# how to use the function time in query myql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have this query :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM news 
 WHERE STATE LIKE 'SI' 
   AND data<'".time()."'  
 ORDER 
    BY data DESC 
 limit 0,1
```

and i would like to know if the function time it's correct because there is an error on synthase.
thank's you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql/Php - Current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618401/mysql-php-current-date-and-time)

Comment: You would normally use `NOW()` in a MySQL query to get the current time. I am also confused by your column name: `data` instead of `date`, what is it? What is the type of that column? That is very important.

Comment: @kikosoftware in Portuguese, Basque, and Catalan (for instance) data means date

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes it could be a mixture of English and an Iberian language. 'SI' would then be 'YES' and 'news' just 'news'. It is unfortunate that 'data' means something else in English.

Comment: ('SELECT * FROM news WHERE STATE LIKE 'yes' AND date<' ".time()." ' ORDER BY date DESC limit 0,1')

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Data is date (timestamp) and si would be yes it's a Italian db

Answer (score 0):

There are reserved words in MySQL which you cannot use as column names without clearly indicating they are names. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Both 'data' and 'date' are reserved words. Use back ticks to indicate they are used as names:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM `news` 
              WHERE `STATE` LIKE 'SI' 
                AND `data` < '".time()."'  
              ORDER 
                BY `data` DESC 
             LIMIT 0,1
```

or better, in my opinion, use better column names:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM newsItems 
             WHERE itemState LIKE 'SI' 
               AND creationDate < '".time()."'  
             ORDER 
                BY creationDate DESC 
             LIMIT 0,1";
```

As you can see I had to guess what the columns really stand for, because it's not directly clear from the names. It should be, because that's what they are there for.

Comment: I do not think it's the words that pose the problem but rather the time function because when I do not use it all functions correctly

Answer (score 0):

`TIME()` is a function in which you also need to pass your parameter.
So, instead of using it blank like:

```
select TIME();
```

you need to use it in this way:

```
select TIME(now());
```

**Note**: In your query, you need to pass like (only if you have *datetime* field in your table):

```
AND time(data) < time(now())
```